# Multiple calls to fit when using LearningRateSchedule

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

if I "compile" a Keras model with an optimizer using a `LearningRateSchedule` and run `model.fit()` for one epoch several times, will it restart the learning rate scheduler every time or will it preserve its state?

```py
model = create_keras_model()
lr_scheduler = create_lr_scheduler()
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr_scheduler)

for i in range(10)
   model.fit(dataset, epochs=1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create lr_scheduler = create_lr_scheduler() inside the for loop? Can you share your scheduler code? if your scheduler is in from of def lr_schedule(epoch): then you can reset it based on epoch.

Comment: The scheduler is just an instance of `PiecewiseConstantDecay`.
I am using this with the `Trainable` interface of the ray tune library, for hyperparameter optimisation, using BOHB I need to serialise the state of the training after each epoch, the easiest way I found for this was to use `model.compile` and then `model.save`, then at each iteration I use `model.fit`, that is what lead to this question. 
I tried creating a new optimiser at each iteration, but the way ray tune functions didn't seen to work with this way of doing... PS: I am new to ray tune.